# Import error in python as a not Root user

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

I have tried to use pyautogui and keyboard library in python but it shows error
[image]

Comment: How did you install PyAutoGUI, please edit the question and include it. Have you downloaded it as a [Wheel](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/) or just `pip install`

Comment: Your titled says "not root" and your prompt say "root". And BTW on Stack Overflow text has to be posted as text, no screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `sudo python3 spam.py` instead of `python3 spam.py`.

You can directly install the library using `pip3 install PyAutoGUI` and `pip3 install keyboard`.